# SHA1 Certificate fingerprint for google-servces.json

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I'm integrating Google Sign-In with my react-native application. On Android, it seems that we'll need to add in our Android SHA certificate fingerprint and re-download the new `google-services.json` in order to get it work.

Which SHA1 fingerprint am I suppose to use?

Since different keystore result in different SHA1, should I have 2 google-services.json for different environment? (Release & Debug)

#### Update

Just notice I can add more than 1 fingerprint to same `google-services.json`. I'm suppose to add in different (release/debug) fingerprint inside the same `google-services.json`?

Comment: You can add multiple SHAs to the GCP right? add both so you can test it on debug and publish the release build.

Comment: I see. So in total the `google-services.json` will be tight with 4 keys? 2 from Debug, 2 from Release? (SHA-1 + SHA 256) x2

Comment: `google-services.json` will not contain SHA keys. It contains the project details, ids and creds. Don't worry about the content within the `google-services.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You may add separate files for debug and release (or for any flavor) like

```
app/src/
    flavor1/google-services.json
    flavor2/google-services.json
```

OR you may also add file in the app/ folder. like

```
app/google-services.json
```